# Parse Error iPhone Retina (4-inch 64bit)

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

I'm using xcode 5. I just got some errors saying:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/wog-khatzpetalio/Desktop/LiveGateApp/NoInterfaceBuilder/LiveGate/Parse.framework/Parse, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/wog-khatzpetalio/Desktop/LiveGateApp/NoInterfaceBuilder/LiveGate/Parse.framework/Parse (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LiveGate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFQuery", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LiveGate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My App is working in all simulator except for iPhone 64 bit.
What should be the possible cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your architectures into this one

[image: Architectures]

Answer (score 0):

It means you do not have the Parse library properly included in your project.  It's possible that something is preventing it from linking, say if the parse library did not support armv64 and you were using the default set of architectures in your project.