# how to add armv7s architecture to static library in xcode 7 / ios 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, xcode7-beta5

Looks like after upgrading to xcode 7 beta 5 and iOS 9.0 beta 5, I can't create a static library that includes an armv7s slice.

> lipo -info staticLibraryName says:

```
Architectures in the fat file: staticLibraryName are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm6.
```

Adding armv7s to build settings alongside $(ARCHS_STANDARD) and setting Build Active Architectures Only to No doesn't not seem to do the trick like it did in xcode 6.

Any one else getting this ? Any way to produce the armv7s slice ? 
If I release a static library without the slice, will my customers \ their end users be affected ?

Comment: You help full just follow step:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375531/how-to-update-our-static-library-architecture-for-suporting-arm64-build

Answer (score 4):

You need set your Xcode setting: Build Setting -> Architectures, add $(ARCHS_STANDARD) & armv7s, Hope it works.

http://7xkptx.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/fwg4whet.png

Comment: i did that but it didn't help in my case.