# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: is x86_64 unsupported?

Tags: ios

[image: screenshot of error]

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABCAppCaller", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GitiTransferAccountsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: where does ABCAppCaller come from?  is it included in your project?  Does this build for the device or are you only having problems building for the simulator?

Comment: Bank to pay, only for the simulator, I have set everything I need， and is the architecture reason？Thank you for your reply！

Comment: And I find this:"Architectures in the fat file: libABCAppCaller.a are: armv7 arm64"   Is this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the people who supplied you with `libABCAppCaller.a` that they need to include symbols for the simulator.

If they ask you "how do I do that?", you can point them to [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375531/how-to-update-our-static-library-architecture-for-suporting-arm64-build), especially the part where they can use `lipo` to link the simulator library and the device library into one universal static library.

Comment: @universe did you solve the problem with the solution that Michael supplied. Any details on the solution?

Comment: @universe, Could you tell me how you fixed this ?
am also facing same issue right now