# is there any change with ios static library run script with xcode 10?

Tags: ios, iphone, static-libraries, xcode10, run-script

I have created a static ios library, and I have created Aggregate target to get an universal library as output for that i have included shell script in the build phase section:

```
# define output folder environment variable
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target OffsetCalLib-Universal ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
xcodebuild -target OffsetCalLib-Universal -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"

# Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

But on build it throws error like:

[image]